# Trying to get the DisplayStats function to iterate through each element of the people arrays

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I am trying to get the function DisplayStats to iterate through each array of people and display the information but it keeps returning some errors I can't figure out. I have the array for each person and then I feed DisplayStats "people[i]" and have a for loop inside DisplayStats to iterate through each person but it keeps telling me i isn't declared in the function call and the formal parameter 1 is incomplete which I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    void DisplayStats(struct person Input[i])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
        printf("%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", Input[i].last, Input[i].first, Input[i].ppg, Input[i].year);
}

struct person
{
    char  first[32];
    char  last[32];
    int   year;
    double ppg;
};

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    struct person people[6];

    people[0].year=2004;
    people[0].ppg=5.2;
    strcpy(people[0].first,"Jane");
    strcpy(people[0].last,"Doe");

    people[1].year = 2007;
    people[1].ppg = 5.9;
    strcpy(people[1].first,"Brian");
    strcpy(people[1].last,"Smith");

    people[2].year = 2020;
    people[2].ppg = 15.3;
    strcpy(people[2].first,"Kevin");
    strcpy(people[2].last,"McAllister");

    people[3].year = 2019;
    people[3].ppg = 24.8;
    strcpy(people[3].first,"Kobe");
    strcpy(people[3].last,"Bryant");

    people[4].year = 2845;
    people[4].ppg = 93.1;
    strcpy(people[4].first,"Offensive");
    strcpy(people[4].last,"Bias");

    people[5].year = 2371;
    people[5].ppg = 7.9;
    strcpy(people[5].first,"Ronald");
    strcpy(people[5].last,"McDonald");

    people[6].year = 1960;
    people[6].ppg = 28.5;
    strcpy(people[6].first,"Weyland");
    strcpy(people[6].last,"Yutani");

    DisplayStats(people[0]);

    return (0);
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
main.c:14:39: error: ‘i’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 void DisplayStats(struct person Input[i])
                                       ^
main.c:14:26: warning: ‘struct person’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 void DisplayStats(struct person Input[i])
                          ^~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:69:15: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
  DisplayStats(people[0]);
```

Comment: You seem to already have an array of structs.  And what exactly do you mean by a "group" of structs?

Comment: @dbush Yeah I was just confusing myself there, I made an edit to the post, I have a new issue

Comment: you seems to have not declare what i is in DisplayStats function

Comment: void DisplayStats(struct person Input[i]) have you declared i here?

Comment: @VanTeoLe yeah if you look at my code it's declared there and in the function as int

Comment: That's not the syntax for declaring a function that takes an array. Try: `void DisplayStats(struct person *Input)`. And you need to move the definition of `struct person` to before it is first used - that is, above `DisplayStats`.

Comment: Move `struct person` definition above `void DisplayStats(struct person Input[i])`  so the function knows what a `struct person` is, or simply put `struct person;` above it as a forward declaration. Also change `input[i]` to either `input[]` or `*input` if passing an array, or simply `input` is passing a single struct by value.

Comment: `DisplayStats(people[0]);` and that's wrong too. The function is defined to take the whole array and not just a single struct. So needs to be `DisplayStats(people);`. But if you want to print a single struct then you need to change the function definition.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you! That worked, I moved struct to top, changed it to *people and got rid of the [0] down in main and it works now

Comment: @kaylum if you do this void DisplayStats(struct person *Input); ,then DisplayStats(people[0]); is still legal

Comment: @VanTeoLe I don't think so. `people[0]` is a `struct person` not a `struct person *`. Unless you are thinking `&people[0]`

Comment: `s[idx].member` notation hurts my eyes: `void DisplayStats(struct person *Input) { struct person *I; for(I=Input; I - Input < 7; I++) printf("%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", I->last, I->first, I->ppg, I->year); }`

Answer (score 0):

@user12982636, hello, this will give the desired result:

```
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <string.h>
      #include <math.h>
      #include <stdio.h>

      struct person
     {
       char  first[32];
       char  last[32];
       int   year;
       double ppg;
     };

     void DisplayStats(struct person *input)
     {
      struct person * i;
      for(i=input; i-input<7; i++)
      printf("%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", i->last, i->first, i->ppg, i->year);
     }

     int main() 
     {
        struct person people[6];
        people[0].year=2004;
        people[0].ppg=5.2;
        strcpy(people[0].first,"Jane");
        strcpy(people[0].last,"Doe");

        people[1].year = 2007;
        people[1].ppg = 5.9;
       strcpy(people[1].first,"Brian");
       strcpy(people[1].last,"Smith");

       people[2].year = 2020;
       people[2].ppg = 15.3;
       strcpy(people[2].first,"Kevin");
       strcpy(people[2].last,"McAllister");

      people[3].year = 2019;
      people[3].ppg = 24.8;
      strcpy(people[3].first,"Kobe");
      strcpy(people[3].last,"Bryant");

      people[4].year = 2845;
      people[4].ppg = 93.1;
      strcpy(people[4].first,"Offensive");
      strcpy(people[4].last,"Bias");

      people[5].year = 2371;
      people[5].ppg = 7.9;
      strcpy(people[5].first,"Ronald");
      strcpy(people[5].last,"McDonald");

      people[6].year = 1960;
      people[6].ppg = 28.5;
      strcpy(people[6].first,"Weyland");
      strcpy(people[6].last,"Yutani");

      DisplayStats(people);

      return (0);
     }
```

Comment: Very poor answer, Because the answer does not describe the reason for the changes and why this answer is better than the OPs posted code.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. eliminates the 'messy' manipulation of the data by moving all the data to a simple table
4. greatly shrinks the amount of code
5. Properly defines the struct before any references to that struct
6. Uses appropriate horizontal and vertial spacing for readability
7. eliminates inclusion of unneeded header files
8. lets the compiler determine the number of instances of 'struct person' is needed
9. folds the `printf` statement to honor the right printer margin

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct person
{
    char  first[32];
    char  last[32];
    int   year;
    double ppg;
};


struct person people[] =
{
    { "Jane",       "Doe",        2004, 5.2  },
    { "Brian",      "Smith",      2007, 5.9  },
    { "Kevin",      "McAllister", 2020, 15.3 },
    { "Kobe",       "Bryant",     2019, 24.8 },
    { "Offensive",  "Bias",       2845, 93.1 },
    { "Ronald",     "McDonald",   2371, 9.5  },
    { "Weyland",    "Yutani",     1960, 28.5 }
};


void DisplayStats( struct person Input[] )
{
    for( int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        printf( "%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", 
            Input[i].last, 
            Input[i].first, 
            Input[i].ppg, 
            Input[i].year);
    }
}


int main( void ) 
{
    DisplayStats( people );

    return (0);
}
```

The output of the proposed code:

```
Doe, Jane: 5.200000 PPG in 2004
Smith, Brian: 5.900000 PPG in 2007
McAllister, Kevin: 15.300000 PPG in 2020
Bryant, Kobe: 24.800000 PPG in 2019
Bias, Offensive: 93.100000 PPG in 2845
McDonald, Ronald: 9.500000 PPG in 2371
Yutani, Weyland: 28.500000 PPG in 1960
```

Suggest limiting the number of digits after the decimal point to 1 or 2 via using a 'output format conversion' specifier similar to `%.2lf`

Suggest formatting the output strings so they all take the same amount of horizontal space.  Similar to `%12.12s` for better output formatting